# Singleton pattern is produced some problems when there are some updates

Tags: java, oracle, database-design, oracle11g, ejb-3.1

> We have an Oracle database which hold data about some cities and
>   places, etc.
>
> We have a web system which we can manipulate these datas.
>
> We also have a desktop client application which is working with these
>   data.

For increasing our desktop application ***performance*** and decreasing unuseful request for our DAO layer, we have implemented some Singleton classes in our desktop application to fetch mentioned cities, places, etc data **only once** right after the user is opened his/her desktop application.

Recently we received a request from our clients why we don't see the changes we make using the web application, when the client desktop application is live and up and running. They're complaining about why they have to close the desktop app and open it again in order to see the changes.

We know that the problem is those ***Singleton classes*** but we don't want to change them because it's gonna be huge overhead in our system when they're not there. For solving the problem we have thought about multiple solutions:

1. Create a table in a database with integer column names similar to our data columns (cities, places, etc) and auto increment value when there's an update for tracking the changes using it (a light weight solution)
2. Using database functionalities
3. a Notify system that notify the client application whenever an update occurred.
4. a caching mechanism inside database that cache those lately changing tables and service our users when they have similar request

Here are our stacks:

- Our Desktop application is **swing** application
- Our Web application is JSF
- Our business layer for both JSF and swing is EJB
- Our Dao layer for both JSF and swing is Eclipse-Link

What do you think is the best practice for solving this problem ?

Comment: Your solution #3 seems like the best option to me, provided the data doesn't change too often.

Comment: @Michael the problem is we have separate systems and we have no idea how to implement this. we also don't want to put timer

Comment: "we have no idea how to implement this" is off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: What about a trivial solution **5. add a `REFRESH` button** similar to browser that would reload the last state of the data. This will resolve the *complaining about why they have to close the desktop app and open it again* and has no need for change data capture, notification etc.

Comment: To extend @MarmiteBomber : If you are using Singletons, you can easily "re-initialize" the Singletons (i.e. run the same "on-startupt" code) on refresh. That way, you can simulate a program restart, but the users will never have to notice it.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber your solution is simple but great

Comment: For solution 2 + 3 + 4 follow this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a feature called "Database Change Notification" that can be used to be notified when read-mostly tables are changed. It looks like this feature could be a good fit to address your requirement. The link to the doc is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815).

In a nutshell, the way it works is that JDBC thin driver in your desktop application would open a port and the Oracle Database would connect to that port and use this connection to push notifications when data changes. You then get a callback through an event/listener API and can refresh your cache.

This notification mechanism is designed for data that is read-mostly, in other words, data that doesn't constantly change otherwise it wouldn't be worth caching the data anyway.

Comment: We use another approach for solving this problem but your solution is a clean and decent solution which deserve to be accepted!